# Promise chain .then .catch

Tags: javascript, promise

How does work this promise chain?

```js
Promise.resolve(1)
  .then(x => console.log(1))
  .catch(x => console.log(2))
  .then(x => console.log(3))

Promise.reject(1)
  .then(x => console.log(4))
  //.then(x => console.log(5))
  .catch(x => console.log(6))
  .then(x => console.log(7))
```

Result 1 6 3 7

Why the result isn't equal 1 3 6 7 ?

If add `.then(x => console.log(5))`, then result is equal 1 3 6 7.
How does it works?

Comment: You should ***not*** expect any specific order of promise resolutions if the promise chains are not linked. The only guarantee you have is that links of the same promise chain resolve in order related to each other. That's it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder did you mean [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+promise+chain+order+user%3A157247+is%3Aanswer)? Yours has `user:me`. I was confused why you thought my answers were relevant :P

Comment: @VLAZ - Yes, thank you. I've answered a question that looks **very** much like this one so I was trying to find it. Thanks for that!

Comment: Please note that VLAZ said above about order. Having said that, the fundamental reason is that promise handlers are called asynchronously, and `then` and `catch` create new promises. You start the first chain off first with a fulfilled promise, so its first `then` handler is called on the next async tick ("1"). You start the second chain off with a rejected handler, so its `catch` handler is called on the next async tick ("6"). Then since those handlers fulfill the promises they return, their handlers are called (the first chain's handler logs "3", the second logs "7").

Comment: But again, although the order between those two chains is defined provided the code is exactly as shown, it's **not** something you should rely on. If you need coordination between the two promise chains, coordinate them intentionally. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder just to add to this - this is the explanation *here* as they are resolved in round-robin order. But is not necessarily applicable for any two promise chains. In some cases, it takes more than one tick to resolve an individual promise, so instead of `a b a b a b` the order might be `a b b b a a`. Hence the recommendation to not rely on anything specific.

Comment: However, with immediately resolving promises, as here, the ECMAScript specification would enforce a specific order to be respected.

Comment: @trincot that is *true* but I fear OP will take "this is why these resolve that way" incorrectly as "expect every single instance of two promise chains to behave like this". Which will be misleading.

Comment: @VLAZ Make that "*in some cases*" a "*in most cases*". You shouldn't use promises at all if you're always immediately resolving them :-)

Comment: @Bergi - Unless you're resolving them to thenables. ;-D Or you have to return a promise on all branches but some branches have no asynchronous processing. Etc.

Comment: @VLAZ - Very good to underscore that. It's also worth noting that some details in this area (though not *quite* in the code above) changed between versions of the ECMAScript spec. So even more reason for he OP -- and all of us -- to follow your original advice. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Did you find a suitable duplicate yet, btw?

Comment: @Bergi - I gave up. I know it's there (I **answered** it, I remember), but...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Same feeling here. I search for keywords like "[promise] unrelated/indepdenent/separate chain order", but all that comes up are [related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62405924/1048572) not this specific case

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned in the comments under the question, you shouldn't rely on the timing or order in which unrelated promises are resolved.

Having said that, there is an explanation of the output your code produces.

Callbacks passed to `then()` and `catch()` methods are invoked asynchronously and are enqueued in a micro-task queue.

1. Calling `Promise.resolve(1)` creates a resolved promise; as a result, the callback passed to `Promise.resolve(1).then(...)` is put in a micro-task queue.

   ```
   [
     (x) => console.log(1)
   ]
   ```
2. After this, `Promise.reject(1)` is called which creates a rejected promise. This will reject the promise returned by `Promise.reject(1).then(...)`.

   ```
   [
     reject(Promise.reject(1).then(...)),
     (x) => console.log(1)
   ]
   ```
3. End of execution of your script
4. Event loop will start processing the micro-task queue which has two tasks in it

   ```
   [
     reject(Promise.reject(1).then(...)),
     (x) => console.log(1)
   ]
   ```
5. `1` is logged on the console. After logging `1`, promise returned by `Promise.resolve(1).then(...)` is fulfilled with the value of `undefined`.

   This will lead to the fulfilment of the promise returned by `Promise.resolve(1).then(...).catch(...)`

   ```
   [
     resolve(Promise.resolve(1).then(...).catch(...))
     reject(Promise.reject(1).then(...))
   ]
   ```
6. Next task in the queue is to reject the promise returned by `Promise.reject(1).then(...)`. This rejection of promise queues another micro-task

   ```
   queue: [
            x => console.log(6),
            resolve(Promise.resolve(1).then(...).catch(...))
          ]

   console output: 1
   ```
7. Promise returned by `Promise.resolve(1).then(...).catch(...)` is resolved which queues `x => console.log(3)` in the micro-task queue

   ```
   queue: [
            x => console.log(3),
            x => console.log(6)
          ]

   console output: 1
   ```
8. "6" is logged on the console

   ```
   queue: [
            x => console.log(3),
          ]

   console output: 1 6
   ```
9. After logging `6`, promise returned by the `catch` method if fulfilled with the value of undefined which queues another micro-task

   ```
   queue: [
            x => console.log(7),
            x => console.log(3)
          ]

   console output: 1 6
   ```
10. `3` is logged on the console

    ```
    queue: [
             x => console.log(7),
           ]

    console output: 1 6 3
    ```
11. `7` is logged on the console

    ```
    queue: []

    console output: 1 6 3 7
    ```

> If add .then(x => console.log(5)), then result is equal 1 3 6 7.

With an extra `then()` method call, it takes an extra step in the micro-task processing cycle to queue

```
x => console.log(6)
```

in the micro-task queue which results in

```
x => console.log(3)
```

getting processed *before* `x => console.log(6)`.