# Asynchronous Execution Order in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why following execution output is `1 3 4 2 6 5`;

```js
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(2));

(async() => console.log(await 6))();

console.log(1);

(async() => await console.log(3))();

Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(5));

console.log(4);
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68784426/promise-chain-then-catch

Comment: Thanks! This thread is related but not helpful enough.

Comment: Find it hard to believe you absorbed all of it's content and other links in two minutes

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: I just found this thread is about promise chain at first, I will check it again.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how your code executes:

1. `Promise.resolve()` creates a resolved promise which puts `() => console.log(2)` in the micro-task queue

   ```
   queue: [ 
      () => console.log(2)
   ]
   ```
2. The IIFE executes in which you have `await 6`. Awaiting 6 is similar to wrapping it in `Promise.resolve(6)` and then awaiting it: `await Promise.resolve(6)`.

   When the operand of `await` is not a promise, `await` creates a native promise and uses the operand's value to resolve that promise

   ```
   queue: [ 
      resolve(6),
      () => console.log(2)
   ]
   ```
3. `1` is logged on the console

   ```
   queue: [ 
      resolve(6),
      () => console.log(2)
   ]

   console output: 1
   ```
4. Second IIFE executes where you have `await console.log(3)`. This is like `await undefined` because `console.log(3)` will execute, `3` will be logged on the console and the return value of `console.log`, i.e. `undefined` will be awaited.

   In short, you are awaiting `undefined`.

   ```
   queue: [ 
      resolve(undefined),
      resolve(6),
      () => console.log(2)
   ]

   console output: 1 3
   ```
5. `Promise.resolve()` creates a resolved promise which puts `() => console.log(5)` in the micro-task queue

   ```
   queue: [ 
      () => console.log(5),
      resolve(undefined),
      resolve(6),
      () => console.log(2)
   ]

   console output: 1 3
   ```
6. `4` is logged on the console

   ```
   queue: [ 
      () => console.log(5),
      resolve(undefined),
      resolve(6),
      () => console.log(2)
   ]

   console output: 1 3 4
   ```
7. Script execution end
8. Event loop will now begin processing the micro-task queue
9. `2` will be logged on the console because it was queued first

   ```
   queue: [ 
      () => console.log(5),
      resolve(undefined),
      resolve(6)
   ]

   console output: 1 3 4 2
   ```
10. `await 6` resolves with the value `6` which is then passed to `console.log`. As a result `6` is logged on the console

    ```
    queue: [ 
       () => console.log(5),
       resolve(undefined)
    ]

    console output: 1 3 4 2 6
    ```
11. Promise created as a result of `await console.log(3)` resolves with the value of `undefined`

    ```
    queue: [ 
       () => console.log(5)
    ]

    console output: 1 3 4 2 6
    ```
12. `5` is logged on the console

    ```
    queue: [ ]

    console output: 1 3 4 2 6 5
    ```
13. Done.

---

**Note:** Your code shouldn't rely on the timing and order in which different unrelated promises are resolved.

Comment: The steps you demonstrated is perfect! I think this resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are two sequences here: `1 3 4` and `2 6 5`. The first is produced on the first tick (before any promises have resolved, and the second on the second tick (after promise resolution).

`(async() => await console.log(3))();` writes `3` to the log before the await, so the `3` appears before any promises resolve, and between 1 and 4 because of the order of the statements. (Note that the `await` in this line resolves to `undefined`, because console.log doesn't return anything).

For the sequence `2 6 5`, all of the console logs come after a promise resolves (or, equivalently, an await statement), and they're in natural order otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

1 is printed first because of order of execution.
3 is printed as code is executed because `console.log()` is not an asynchronous operation. Does not matter if you put await in front of it.
4 is again printed because of order of execution.

Now, rest of the order of execution is due to asynchronous operations. The 3 statements are printed in an asynchronous manner after the above 3 statements are executed.

Comment: Does the await of 3 block the codes below?

Comment: @young-trigold no, it does not.