# The execution sequence when returning a Promise object in promise then mehod

Tags: javascript, promise

The code is:

```js
Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    console.log(0);
    return Promise.resolve(4);
}).then((res) => {
    console.log(res)
})

Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    console.log(1);
}).then(() => {
    console.log(2);
}).then(() => {
    console.log(3);
}).then(() => {
    console.log(5);
}).then(() =>{
    console.log(6);
})
```

And the result is: `0 1 2 3 4 5 6`.

Why `log 4`  is after `log 3`? What is the special thing happened when returning a `promise object` in `.then` method?

Comment: Related questions: [Asynchronous Execution Order in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68882535/asynchronous-execution-order-in-javascript) and [Promise chain .then .catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68784426/promise-chain-then-catch)

Comment: Keep in mind that questions like this are really only useful for intellectual curiosity.  If there are real asynchronous operations and you care about the relative order of execution in two separate promise chains, then you have to write the code to control the sequencing the way you want it - you don't rely on anything that you will get as an answer to this question because it won't be relevant with real asynchronous operations.

Comment: _"What is the special thing happened when returning a promise object in .then method?"_ Returning a promise from the callback function of `then()` method's callback function _resolves_ the promise returned by the `then` method to the promise returned by its callback function. See: [MDN - then() Return Value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#return_value)

Comment: While there is an answer to this question (that is related to the specification of Promises) the answer is not useful at all. **DO NOT DEPEND ON THE KNOWLEDGE of how this code works**. It's OK if you are curious but then completely forget about the answer. Depending on things like this is a source of bugs. You need to write asynchrnous code to be independent of each other. If they are dependent you need to explicitly make it dependent (call resolve(4) inside then(()=>console.log(3)))

Answer (score 1):

Javascript runs an event loop.

Here is my guess.

`Promise.resolve()` creates a promise which will be resolved in the next iteration. And every then block will be execute in the next iteration after the previous block finish. So here is the execution order:

Iteration 1: Created 2 promises (name them A and B) which will be resolved in Iteration 2

Iteration 2: Promise A resolves. Promise B resolves

Iteration 3: `then` block of Promise A executes, which prints 0 and creates a new promise (name it C) which will be resolved in Iteration 4. First `then` block of the Promise B executes, which prints 1.

Iteration 4: Second `then` block of Promise B executes, which prints 2. Promise C resolves. (Since Promise C is added to the event loop later than Promise B, Promise B resolves before Promise C)

Iteration 5: Third `then` block of Promise B executes, which prints 3. `then` block of Promise C executes, which prints 4.

Iteration 6: Forth `then` block of Promise B executes, which prints 5.

Iteration 7: Fifth `then` block of Promise B executes, which prints 6.

Comment: Promises don't execute; they resolve (or not).

Comment: The sequence of log 3 and then 4 is not always true. It could be log 4 then 3.

Comment: @trincot thanks. I edited my wording. I have been thinking on the wording but finally chose the wrong one.

Comment: @ikhvjs I uses chrome developer console to try that piece of code and have never got 4 before 3.